# Parsing JSON reponse in jQuery for only first value

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to parse the json

```
[{
        "resourceName": "Jasmine Room",
        "totalStaff": "15"            
    },
    {
        "resourceName": "Lily Room",
        "totalStaff": "15"           
    }]
```

I dont want to iterate over it using each, just I want the first resourceName value. Is is coming success call backback of an ajax call as data.

So I tried like this `data[0].resourceName` but it is not working.

Comment: please check the developer console in browser and tell what it says

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid it is saying data[o] is undefined.

Comment: first try to alert(data) ; see if it comes

Comment: it is working in my console.

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid it is  saying [object][object] on using alert with data.

Comment: How is the data being encoded before reaching your JS script? Are you using AJAX to call a server-side script which gives you this JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are receiving JSON in text format, you can try parsing string into JSON like this

```
var json = '[{"resourceName": "Jasmine Room","totalStaff": "15"},{"resourceName": "Lily Room","totalStaff": "15"}]';
console.log(json[0].resourceName); // doesn't work
json =  $.parseJSON(json);
console.log(json[0].resourceName); // work after parsing json
```

Demo `------>`  http://jsfiddle.net/rcvvL/1/

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this sometimes...

```
$.post("filename.ext",{
    request:"parameter",
},function(d){
    var ret = d['DATA'][0];
    if(ret != undefined){
        var resourceName = ret.resourceName;
    }
},'json');
```

should work?

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the json first using the `JSON.parse` function.

Something like this:
`var json = JSON.parse(data);
return json[0].resourceName`

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Comment: Maybe the json is not correctly formatted, how are you generating the json string on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine for me.

```
var temp = [{
        "resourceName": "Jasmine Room",
        "totalStaff": "15"            
    },
    {
        "resourceName": "Lily Room",
        "totalStaff": "15"           
    }]
console.log(temp[0].resourceName);
```

Is it because you are trying to do `data[o]` instead of `data[0]` like in one of your 
comments?

Comment: o instead of 0 is mistake in typing the comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = [{
        "resourceName": "Jasmine Room",
        "totalStaff": "15"            
    },
    {
        "resourceName": "Lily Room",
        "totalStaff": "15"           
    }];
    alert(json[0].resourceName);
```

this should work